# What causes NextJS Warning: "Extra attributes from the server: data-new-gr-c-s-check-loaded... "

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, next.js

I am getting the following warning from my NextJS Application:

> Warning: Extra attributes from the server: data-new-gr-c-s-check-loaded,data-gr-ext-installed,cz-shortcut-listen,data-lt-installed

I don't know why it happens, what is the explanation for this?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Disabling the Grammarly extension solved the problem for me.

Comment: It's little strange, disabling both grammarly and colorzilla extentions fixed the issue.

Comment: I had a problem with Grammarly, if someone use other one, need to disable that also for fixing the error.

Answer (score 379):

This is usually **caused by an extension** passing these extra attributes with your code when it is executed on the browser trying to interact with the UI, this creates a mismatch between what was rendered on the server and what is rendered on the client.

Extensions similar to **Grammarly**, **ColorZilla** and **LanguageTool** are therefore **the cause of this warning**, so you have to find out which one is doing this and then **disable/configure** it to not run on the ports you usually use for development. **This is the straightforward fix for the warning**, since it is always **recommended** to avoid extensions in development.

---

You can find those extra attributes if you inspect the app pure HTML in the `Elements` section of the devTools

[image]

An abbreviation is usually used, like here, `lt` stands for **LanguageTool**, `gr` for **Grammaly**, and `cz` for **ColorZilla**. this can help detect the extension.

---

**Good to know:**

You can suppress hydration warnings by setting `suppressHydrationWarning` to `true` in the opening `<body>` tag of the RootLayout:

```js
export default RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
   <html lang="en">
      <body suppressHydrationWarning={true}>
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

sometimes you have to put it in the opening `<html>` tag if attributes are added there

```html
<html lang="en" suppressHydrationWarning={true}>
```

[suppresshydrationwarning](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/client/hydrateRoot#suppressing-unavoidable-hydration-mismatch-errors)  only works one level deep so if you put it in the `<html>` element, it won't suppress [hydration](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/client/hydrateRoot#hydrating-server-rendered-html) warnings for the `<body>` element since it is in a deeper level, that's great! because we don't want to suppress hydration warnings for our server components which are in a deeper level.

Comment: I added the attribute and it worked.  Then I removed the extensions which I've not used since ages and also removed the attribute and it worked too.  Thanks for your answer, it helped me clean up my browser : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wgrmB8M0sgU&t=214s&pp=ygUKbWFuIGRyYXdlcg%3D%3D

Comment: This `suppressHydrationWarning` prop fixed it for me, but the error should specify which element is throwing the error. Mine was `input`, `form`, and `button` elements within my server actions (which are experimental still, so that might be the issue).

Comment: @douglasrcjames It is not an error it is a warning, and it will not harm anything, what is more recommended is to disable extensions when developing

Comment: FYI that if you have a class on the HTML tag this will always fire up the error.

Comment: @Moayad.AlMoghrabi in fact better is to disable extensions in dev mode, the second solution is just an alternative

Comment: I guess you are right, unfortunately for me, disabling Grammarly did not do the trick and I just have like a ton of extensions. so I went to Edge now. However, in production, will I still be seeing these errors?

Comment: @Moayad.AlMoghrabi first it is not an error it is a warning and it is ok to ignore it.

Comment: Suppressing the hydration warning in a React Server Component architecture is a pretty dumb suggestions. People upvote the biggest sht sadly

Comment: @Pagenotfound I updated my answer, in docs they mentioned that `suppressHydrationWarning` only works one level deep so if you put it in the body element it shouldn't affect server components which are in a deeper level

Comment: Thanks for the comment, in my case, was Grammarly, the fix was to disable the writing checking in localhost (there is an option for this in the plugin)

Comment: `<body suppressHydrationWarning={true}>` works well

Comment: What about production? What if the final user does have that extension? Will that cause the hydration to also fail but just without showing an error?

Comment: I removed ColorZilla extension from browser, it works, warning disappeared after removing extension, Thanks!!!

Comment: "Adblock Plus - free ad blocker" was causing it for me ....

Answer (score 32):

disabling ColorZilla extension solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 31):

Chrome has released a new feature to disable extensions for specific URLs which is great, since this warning seems to just be a development environment issue. Simply put `chrome://flags/#extensions-menu-access-control` into your Chrome browser to enable this flag and restart Chrome.

After you restart you can click on the extensions icon (in the upper-right corner of your browser), while you are browsing `http://localhost:3000` URL, to toggle off your extensions for that URL (only)! No need for the `suppressHydrationWarning={true}` prop mentioned above.

[image]

Comment: Excellent - thanks a bunch

Comment: This is brilliant, if you're developing on Chrome it's the way to go. It's also a generally useful Chrome tip - thanks for sharing.

Comment: Thanks for this tip. I had other extensions that I didn't want to use while I am working.

Answer (score 15):

Stop `ColorZilla` and `Grammarly` extensions fix my problem.

[image]

**Update:** more extensions that are causing related issues:

- [ColorZilla](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/colorzilla/bhlhnicpbhignbdhedgjhgdocnmhomnp)
- [Grammarly](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/grammarly-grammar-checker/kbfnbcaeplbcioakkpcpgfkobkghlhen)
- [Wikiwand: Wikipedia Modernized](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wikiwand-wikipedia-modern/emffkefkbkpkgpdeeooapgaicgmcbolj)

  - Error message: `Warning: Extra attributes from the server: style`
  - Solution: Change `Site Access` extension option, from `On all sites` to `on specific sites` and enter the URL: `https://*.wikipedia.org/*`

Comment: its the grammarly for me. thanks

Answer (score 5):

In my case Disabling the Grammarly and ColorZilla extension solved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

This warning message indicates that there are some extra attributes on the HTML element that Next.js received from the server that it does not recognize.
These attributes are added by various browser extensions, plugins, or toolbars that modify the HTML of the page.

In your case, the attributes `data-new-gr-c-s-check-loaded`, `data-gr-ext-installed`, and `cz-shortcut-listen` are likely being added by one or more browser
extensions that are installed in your browser. These attributes are not recognized by Next.js, which is why it is warning you about them.

To get rid of the warning, you can filter out the `data-*` attributes that next.js does not recognize by using the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` prop on the element.

```
<div 
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML = {{
        __html: htmlString.replace(
            / data-(?!react[\w-]+=)[\w-]+="[^"]*"/g,
            ''
        ),
    }}
/>
```

Comment: How should I set the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`? Should I do it on the `<body>` tag in the `layout.tsx`(`_app.tsx`)? And what should I replace `htmlString` with since I don't really know where the browser extension could have injected those attributes?

Answer (score 4):

### 1. Disable extensions

The warning message you're seeing in your JavaScript console, specifically:

> Warning: Extra attributes from the server: cz-shortcut-listen...

is related to some attributes being sent from the server that your code might not be handling properly or expecting. This warning is typically not critical and doesn't prevent your application from running, but it's a good practice to address it to ensure that your code remains clean and maintainable.

Temporarily disable browser extensions, except for those required for development in your browser. Browser extensions can sometimes interfere with the behavior of web applications, including altering the content of network requests or injecting additional attributes into HTML elements.

or

### 2. Prevent hydration

Add `suppressHydrationWarning={true}` in the opening tag of `<body>`.

Example: `<body className={inter.className} suppressHydrationWarning={true}> your code</body>`

[image: Example]

Answer (score 3):

In the app folder and your layout.js file should be like below:

```
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className} suppressHydrationWarning={true}>
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Comment: This worked for me by adding suppressHydrationWarning={true} to the body tag as follows : <body className={inter.className} suppressHydrationWarning={true}>{children}</body>

Answer (score 3):

You should add `suppressHydrationWarning` on the html tag.

```
<html lang="en" suppressHydrationWarning>
  <body className={`${inter.className} antialiased`}>
    <ThemeProvider
      attribute="class"
      defaultTheme="system"
      enableSystem
      disableTransitionOnChange
    >
      {children}
    </ThemeProvider>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many Google Extensions for CSS measurements and edits. Most of them are producing errors.

So, after disabling the *Measurement* extension for the page removed the error.

Answer (score 2):

Since this seems to be an issue in development, the following worked for me:

```
export default function RootLayout({ children }: RootLayoutProps) {
    const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'

    return (
        <html lang="en" suppressHydrationWarning={isDev}>
            <body className={inter.className}>
                <AppProvider>
                    <MainLayout>
                        {children}
                    </MainLayout>
                </AppProvider>
            </body>
        </html>
    )
}
```

This makes it so you won't have to change your browser settings in every browser you cross test in.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid this error go to the extensions and switch off your developer mode.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with the 1688.com plugin that analyzes images in my browser. After disconnecting the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add to this - if anyone is using chrome extension Grammarly or similar extensions, this causes the same issue as it adds these attributes to the `<body/>` tag

I was getting the same warning and could not figure it out, I thought it was my UI library but then with some help from the community we were able to figure out it from from a chrome extension.

Once I removed Grammarly this warning never came back! Hope this helps anyone else in the same situation that gets directed to this post!

Answer (score 0):

also if you are using multiple route layouts with html / body and then you have a top level one also with html / body elements, it will cause this error.

If you are experiencing this, remove all children group layouts html / body elements and just leave them at the top root one